# Split one datatable into 2

Tags: database-design

I have a database table, which is constantly updated and read. It contains about 15 columns, where I update about 5 of them. 2 of them are critically important, 3 less important, but also. Unfortunately I keep seeing in the logs:

process 40900 acquired ShareLock on transaction 50309403 after 4150.000 ms

I think simply 2 different processes want to update same row. I was wondering, if it would be wise to split this table, so those two columns groups will be separated into 2 tables? Of course the downside is that another table would have to be indexed/look up.

What's your opinion?

Comment: Knowing what DB you are using would maybe help? I guess Postgres, but please specify version, too - and what language you are using to access it (all of these may help offer better strategies).

Comment: A lot also depends on how you are using the data. It could be that some normalization will also help, apart from splitting it out just for performance. Btw, if the transaction that's locking the table for too long is updating those 5 columns only, splitting out the rest is not going to help.

Comment: so is it correct, that

UPDATE table SET column1 = val WHERE id = someid

will run faster than 

UPDATE table SET  column1 = val1, column2 = val2, .... WHERE id = someid

? If yes, updating the tables using EJB entity beans does not much sense in terms of performance... Correct?